# unused import even after i import the component in react

Tags: reactjs, react-component

i imported the component called "home" and use that component inside the "div" tag as you can see below

```
import './App.css';
import home from './Component/Home/home.js';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <home/>
      <h2>This is h2 file</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

And my home component is here

```
const home = () =>
{
    return(
         <div className="myname">
             <h1>This is heading 1</h1>
         </div>
    );
}
export default home;
```

But the problem is unable to read that component and returns unused import. can any one explain it why that is happened ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to name the component with capital letters, it is a must.

so you need to change your `home` component to be `Home`.

this is how you use it:

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './Component/Home/home.js';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Home/>
      <h2>This is h2 file</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

and this is your home component:

```
const Home = () =>
{
    return(
         <div className="myname">
             <h1>This is heading 1</h1>
         </div>
    );
}
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

the component first character must be in capital

Comment: yeah thank you bro. and i was solved it myself.